# rails yaml fixture - specify NULL value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, null, yaml, fixtures

I have a fixture with values like this:

```
product_four:
     id: 4
     application_id: 1
     title: "oldtitle"
     deleted_at: ~
```

Setting up a postgresql database for testing.
But I can't figure out how to set the deleted_at field to NULL rather than [empty].
I've tried:

```
deleted_at: :null
deleted_at: <%= nil %>
deleted_at: ~
deleted_at: NULL
```

And probably a couple more, without luck.
Clues for the clueless?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just leave the value out:

```
product_four:
     id: 4
     application_id: 1
     title: "oldtitle"
     deleted_at:
```

For example:

```
> {:k => ''}.to_yaml
 => "--- \n:k: \"\"\n" 
> {:k => nil}.to_yaml
 => "--- \n:k: \n" 
> YAML.load({:k => nil}.to_yaml)
 => {:k=>nil}
```

Note that `k:` means that `k` has a `nil` value whereas `k: ""` means that `k` has an empty string as its value.

You could also use an explicit [`null`](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2803362) if all your parsers are aware of the latest YAML spec:

```
product_four:
     id: 4
     application_id: 1
     title: "oldtitle"
     deleted_at: null
```

For example:

```
> YAML.load("--- \n:k: null\n")
 => {:k=>nil}
```

Comment: Actually, it seems most of those methods work.
psql just doesn't show NULL as the value, it just doesn't print anything.
Thanks anyway. Leaving it empty also works.